# How many FAA-Certified Flight Instructors Hold a Gold Seal?

Tags: faa, pilot-certification, cfi, statistics

About how many, and approximately what percent of the instructors who are certified under the FAA hold a gold seal on their CFI certificate?

How many ***not including*** expired certificates capable of being renewed via a reinstatement ride?

How many ***including*** expired certificates capable of being renewed via a reinstatement ride?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this information is not publicly available. You may be able to submit an open records request (FOIA) to the FAA for this, but nothing on the FAA website provides information about gold seal instructors or certificate status.